# How to export a map to fullscreen way (using OpenLayer)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, openlayers

I have the following code and It works perfectly:

```
  <style>
    .map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 350px;
    }
  </style>

  <div id="map" class="map"></div>

  /* Export map to PNG Format */
  var exportPNGElement = document.getElementById('pngFormat');

  if ('download' in exportPNGElement) {
    exportPNGElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      map.once('postcompose', function(event) {
        var canvas = event.context.canvas;
        exportPNGElement.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      });
      map.renderSync();
    }, false);
  } else {
    var info = document.getElementById('no-download');
    /**
     * display error message
     */
    info.style.display = '';
  }
```

But now, I'd like to export all this to fullscreen way.

I've tried to insert the following code but It doesn't work.

```
canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

Also, I've tried to resize the div map but without sucessful.

```
var maptoEdit = document.getElementById('map').innerHTML = "<div style='height:100%; width:100%'></div>";
```

Comment: Your resize approach will just fill the element with an empty div. WHat is source of map?

Comment: What does not work? It can be troubling working with `canvas` and percentages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Finally, I can do it the next way:

```
//document.getElementById('map').style.width = $(window).width() + 'px'; // Returns width of browser viewport
//document.getElementById('map').style.height= $(window).height() + 'px'; // Returns height of browser viewport  
document.getElementById('map').style.width = '1280px'; 
document.getElementById('map').style.height = '768px'; 
map.updateSize();
```